# Mockito + Spring + @PostConstruct, mock initialization error, why is @PostConstruct called?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

I have a set up like:

**Bean** class:

```
private final Map<String, String> configCache = new HashMap<>();
@PostConstruct
private void fillCache() {  (...) configCache.clear();}
```

**TestConfig** class:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Primary
public Bean beanMock() {
    return Mockito.mock(Bean.class);
}
```

**Test** class: which `@Autowires` the bean.

It seems when Mockito is creating the mock in TestConfig, it calls @PostConstruct which in turn seems to be called before the map field is initialized so it throws an exception.

My question is:

- Why does Mockito call @PostConstruct?
- How can I disable @PostConstruct for mocking?

EDIT: Apparently the call is done after the instantiation just before Spring retrns the bean from a Config's @Bean method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockito isn't calling `@PostConstruct` -- Spring is.  You say that in your test you use `@Autowired`, which is not a Mockito annotation.

If you meant to use `@Mock`, you'll find that Mockito won't call your `@PostConstruct` method.

In other words, write your test class like this:

```
@Mock Bean myBean;

@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks();
}
```

Comment: You seem to be right. It's Spring!! But it's called after the return of the instance in `@Configuration`'s `@Bean` method. How can I disable it?

Comment: I donot think you can.  Unless you are writing an integration test for multiple components, you're better off using mocks for unit testing.