# NullPointerException from mocked bean in a constructor - How can I correctly mock a mockBean from constructor by customizing it first?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I am using a @MockBean annotation in my test class for a WebClient.Builder instance and it is leading to a NullPointerException when I  try to set SSL context.

I am not sure why I did not see an error when I was not trying to set the context and simply calling build() api as in v1 show below:

Service class v1:

```
@Service
public class ABCD {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ABCD.class);

private String apiUrl;

private final WebClient webClient;
private final XYZRepository repository;

public ABCD(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
                   XYZRepository repository, @Value("${api-root-url}") String apiUrl) {

    //------------------------
    this.webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
    //------------------------
    this.repository = repository;
    this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
    }
}
```

Service class v2:

```
@Service
public class ABCD {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ABCD.class);

private String apiUrl;

private final WebClient webClient;
private final XYZRepository repository;

public ABCD(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
                   XYZRepository repository, @Value("${api-root-url}") String apiUrl) throws SSLException {

    SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();
    ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(options -> options.sslContext(sslContext));

    //------------------------
    this.webClient = webClientBuilder
            .clientConnector(httpConnector)
            .build();
    //------------------------
    this.repository = repository;
    this.apiUrl = apiUrl;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(ABCD.class)
public class ABCDTest {

    @MockBean
    XYZRepository repository;

    @MockBean
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @SpyBean
    ABCD ABCDService;


    WebClient webClient;

    @Value("${api-root-url}")
    String apiRootUrl;

    @Before
     public void setup() {
         this.objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         this.mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
         String baseUrl = this.mockWebServer.url("/").toString();
         this.webClient = WebClient.create(baseUrl);

         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
         ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ABCDService,
                 "apiRootUrl", API_ROOT_URL);
         ReflectionTestUtils.setField(ABCDService,
                 "webClient", this.webClient);
     }

    }
```

Here in v2

this.webClient = webClientBuilder
                .clientConnector(httpConnector)
                .build();

causes an NPE on ***build()*** call. How can I mock webclient without an causing NPE?

I tried, adding following code in setup() method to mock the clientConnector method's response:

```
when(this.webClientBuilder.clientConnector(any()))
                .thenReturn(this.webClientBuilder);
```

So, I am curious where this code can be added to use the mocking above.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the `webClientBuilder` has been created OK as a mock (it is not-null - yes?), but you haven't told that mock what to do when the `clientConnector` method is called on it.  Mockito's default behaviour is therefore to return null - hence your NPE when you call `build()` on that response.

So you'll need the `webClientBuilder` to return itself from the `clientConnector` method, and to return the `webClient` from the `build()`.  Do this by adding the following lines :

```
when(webClientBuilder.clientConnector(any(ClientHttpConnector.class))).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(webClient);
```

Comment: Agreed and I had tried to mock using exactly the same code before. But I haven't been able to find appropriate place to put that code. I should have mentioned this in the question. I tried adding it to setup() method but that was obviously late as ABCD's constructor call was made before that method.

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html looks like \@SpyBean should be applied to your mocks, not the ABCDservice under test (use \@Autowired ?).  2) Your constructor is doing too much - it should simply be setting the instance variables.  Try moving initialisation of WebClient to an \@PostConstruct method - gives you a few more options (eg, use MockitoJUnitRunner as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112625/mockito-spring-postconstruct-mock-initialization-error-why-is-postconstr?rq=1 )